# Is there a way to store schema locally for F# SQL TypeProviders?

Tags: sql, sql-server, f#, type-providers

I'm making use of the FSharp.Data.SqlClient SQL type providers, and I wanted to know if there was a way to store the database schema locally.

For other type providers, like JSON or YAML, you're able to store a sample locally so that the type provider knows the "shape" of the incoming data. I was wanting to do the same for the SQL type provider.

Yes, I realize that would mean regenerating to store locally each time there is a change in the schema.

Comment: The answer is no https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/178

Comment: @xuanduc987 That's another type provider :) But FSharp.Data.SqlClient can't either. Sql.Data.TypeProviders.SqlDataConnection/SqlEntityConnection can though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different providers have different capabilities. `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` and `SQLProvider` currently cannot do this. But the (formerly built-in) `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders`'s `SqlDataConnection` and `SqlEntityConnection` can:

```
open FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type MyDb = SqlDataConnection<connectionString, 
                LocalSchemaFile = "mydb.dbml",
                ForceUpdate = false>
```

This will save the schema in the file `mydb.dbml`, and subsequent compiles will load it from there instead of connecting to the database. If you need to update the file because the schema has changed, just set `ForceUpdate` to `true`, recompile, then set it back to `false`. You can commit the `dbml` file and people will be able to compile the project without access to the database.